# How to freeze the ML network except one layer

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network, freeze

I have below CNN architecture and forward pass function. I want to freeze all layer except last layer. How can I do that? I have trained this model on one dataset therefore I have all trained weights.

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=2, out_channels=4, kernel_size=4)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(4, 8, 4)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8 * 6 * 6, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        # -> n, 3, 32, 32
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))  # -> n, 6, 14, 14
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))  # -> n, 16, 5, 5
        x = x.flatten()           # -> n, 400
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))               # -> n, 120
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))               # -> n, 84
        # x = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)(self.fc3(x))                      # -> n, 10
        x = self.fc3(x)                      # -> n, 10
        return x
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from torch import nn

class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=2, out_channels=4, kernel_size=4)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(4, 8, 4)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8 * 6 * 6, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        # -> n, 3, 32, 32
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))  # -> n, 6, 14, 14
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))  # -> n, 16, 5, 5
        x = x.flatten()           # -> n, 400
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))               # -> n, 120
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))               # -> n, 84
        # x = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)(self.fc3(x))                      # -> n, 10
        x = self.fc3(x)                      # -> n, 10
        return x

net = ConvNet()

for n, p in net.named_parameters():
    if not 'fc3' in n:
        p.requires_grad = False
```